# Does Irelia's passive stack with Mercury's Treads?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am starting to play a lot of top laners to get ready for my team when I stumbled upon Irelia.  I just want to know if Mercury's Treads stack with her passive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**

Tenacity stack multiplicatively with other forms of Crowd Control reduction.

Since everything that provides Tenacity right now gives 35 Tenacity, Irelia with any of the CC reduction items will have the following stats

```
Ionian Fervor stacks multiplicatively with tenacity:
1 champion: 41.5%
2 champions: 51.25%
3 champions: 61%
```

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Irelia_the_Will_of_the_Blades

---

**gbn**'s answer is correct. But I think it's helpful to show the details here.

Comment: It also stacks with the Juggernaut mastery.

Comment: However, you can't stack tenacity with other items, as it's a unique passive with the name Tenacity on it.

Comment: @Fabián Can you verify this? Her abilities details page doesn't mention it being named Tenacity. And it specifically says that it "stacks multiplicatively with Tenacity".

Comment: @Atav32 I'm sorry, I expressed myself wrong: you cannot stack tenacity with more than one item (i.e. mercury and zephyr together).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, according to [League of Legends Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Irelia_the_Will_of_the_Blades/Ability_Details) because [Mercury's Treads](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Mercury%27s_Treads) provide Tenacity. The same would apply to the other [Tenacity](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Tenacity) items too.

I haven't tested this...